# "record" object is not recognized in custom page template

Tags: symfony, twig, bolt-cms

I created a custom page template for my bolt cms homepage and named it `home.twig`.

I setup the `homepage_template:home.twig` value in the `theme.yml` to display the homepage with `home` template, and I used this template value in administration area as a template for my homepage.

Inside my `home.twig` template I have the following code:

`{% extends 'partials/_base.twig' %}
 {% block main %} 
    {{ record.title }}
    {{ record.body }}
 {% endblock main %}`

The problem is: `record` object is throwing a twig error:

`Twig_Error_Runtime in Template.php line 487: 
Variable "record" does not exist in "home.twig" at line 5.`

What am I doing wrong? Is this a template error (even the error suggests is a template problem), or is a misconfiguration problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind... the problem is with the main configuration file from the `app` folder.
The `config.yml` also contains 2 fields for homepage configuration:

`homepage: page/home
 homepage_template: home.twig`

For some reason, even though you configure the `theme.yml` config file, to use some custom template for your homepage, the template engine throws an error while trying to get the template (the problem is the homepage URL row, even if you configure the correct page template).